# How to calculate Angles it would take to rotate from one vector to another?

Tags: graphics, vector, 3d

I have two normalized vectors:
A) 0,0,-1
B) 0.559055,0.503937,0.653543

I want to know, what rotations about the axes would it take to take the vector at 0,0,-1 to 0.559055,0.503937,0.653543?

How would I calculate this?  Something like, rotate over X axis 40 degrees and Y axis 220 (that's just example, but I don't know how to do it).

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors) out. (google is a good thing)

This calculates the angle between two vectors.
If Vector A is (ax, ay, az)    and
Vector B is (bx, by, bz),  then

The cos of angle between them is:

```
                     (ax*bx + ay*by + az*bz)
    --------------------------------------------------------
    sqrt(ax*ax + ay*ay + az*az) * sqrt(bx*bx + by*by + bz*bz)
```

To calculate the angle between the two vectors as projected onto the x-y plane, just ignore the z-coordinates.

Cosine of Angle in x-y plane =

```
                (ax*bx + ay*by)
    --------------------------------------
    sqrt(ax*ax + ay*ay) * sqrt(bx*bx + by*by
```

Similarly, to calculate the angle between the projections of the two vectors in the x-z plane, ignore the y-coordinates.

Comment: That gets one angle.   I don't know what it means?  I want the angles over the x,y rotations that it would take me from 0,0,-1 to 0.559055,0.503937,0.653543.  I get one angle out of this, what do I do with it?

Comment: This calculates the angle, what you do with it is up to you... What are you calculating it for?  Do you want this angle nroken up into two components ?

Comment: That doesn't tell me how I get from 0,0,-1 to 0.559055,0.503937,0.653543 in 3D (3 angles).  It gets 130 degrees approximately, but that is not in rotation over X, Y, and Z axes.

Comment: It is a single rotation, in the plane formed by the two vectors, directly from the first vector to the other. If you want to know how this would be done moving in discrete steps, that's a different problem that has no definitive answer.  You could move from A to B in any number of different ways if you can move in multiple steps.

Comment: Yes that's the problem I'm trying to solve.  Is there an iterative algorithm or some way to do this?

Comment: If you want the three angles representing the projection of the 130 degree angle on the x-y plane, the x-z plane, and the y-z plane, just take the coordinates of the original A and B vectors in the plane you want to measure the projection in.  see my edited example

Comment: Is there any way you could show me using my example?  I think then I'd follow better.

Comment: Read edited answer at bottom, For the calculation about the angle in the x-y plane, (which is about the z-axis), think about looking at the two vectors from a point far away in the positive z direction. All you will see is the x and y coordinates, and the perceived angle between what you see is the angle you are trying to calculate, right?

Comment: Hmm, it didn't appear to work correctly.  I get 139, 0/0, and 142 for the axes. XZ, XY, YZ
<code>
D3DXVECTOR3 a(0,0,-1);
 D3DXVECTOR3 b(0.559055,0.503937,0.653543);
 float anglexz = CalculateXZAngleBetweenVectorsDegrees(&a, &b);
[code]
D3DXVECTOR2 vec2d1(v1->x, v1->z);
 D3DXVECTOR2 vec2d2(v2->x, v2->z);
 float dotProduct = D3DXVec2Dot(&vec2d1, &vec2d2);
 float magnitudeMultiply = (sqrt((v1->x * v1->x) + (v1->z * v1->z)) * sqrt((v2->x * v2->x) + (v2->z * v2->z)));
 float inverse = dotProduct / magnitudeMultiply;
 float angle = acos(inverse);
 angle = angle *(180/PI);
 return angle;
}
</code>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying convert from Cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) into spherical coordinates (rho,theta,psi).

Since they're both unit vectors, *rho*, the radius, will be 1. This means your magnitudes will also be 1 and you can skip the whole denominator and just use the dot-product.

Rotating in the X/Y plane (about the Z axis) will be very difficult with your first example (0,0,-1) because it has no extension in X or Y. So there's nothing to rotate.

(0,0,-1) is 90 degrees from (1,0,0) or (0,1,0).  If you take the x-axis to be the 0-angle for theta, then you calculate the *phi* (rotation *off* of the X/Y plane) by applying the inverse cos upon (x,y,z) and (x,y,0), *then* you can skip dot-products and get theta (the x/y rotation) with atan2(y,x).

Beware of [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) which may cause problems.